# capistrano symlink permission denied

Tags: capistrano, symlink, permission-denied

I am using cap deploy to deploy to staging. cap deploy:setup created the releases and shared folder.

This is the deploy.rb code.

```
set :stages, %w(staging production)
set :default_stage, "staging"
set :stage_dir, "capistrano"
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

set :application, "application"
set :repository,  "git@github.com:owner/#{application}.git"
set :scm, :git

set :local_user, ENV['USER'] || ENV['USERNAME'] || "unknown"
set :user, "server_owner"

set :deploy_via, :copy

set :use_sudo, false
set :copy_remote_dir, "/home/#{user}/tmp/capistrano"

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Change Permissions" 
  task :change_permissions, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "find #{current_path}/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \\;"
    run "find #{current_path}/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \\;"
  end

  desc "Create symlinks for shared items"
  task :update_shared_symlinks, :except => { :no_release => true} do
     < ln -s command to create the links>
  end
end

before "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:update_shared_symlinks"
```

And this is the staging code

```
role :app, "ipaddress"

set :branch, "staging"

set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/_#{application}_beta/"
```

When deploying with cap deploy i get the following error

ln: creating symbolic link `/home/narayan/_instaprint_beta/releases/20130130102815/': Permission denied

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Why do you want to set the permissions by hand? Also why don't you use something like chmod -R #{current_path}?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Use `chmod` straight away instead of a `find` and `exec`, like so: `chmod 755 #{current_path}`
2. Check if the `server_owner` user has permission to `current_path`. If not, then use `sudo` like so: `sudo "chmod 755 #{current_path}"`